# Moving Month Stored Procedure Query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-order-by

I am creating a stored procedure with a moving month concept. The idea is that the current month should have the highest priority, followed by the previous month, then the month before. How do I write a query that automatically orders in this manner?

A fix 12 month period is given. Month column can be assumed as either int or 3-letter string.

For example, this month is `Jul`, the sequence should be `Jul, Jun, May, Apr, Mar, Feb, Jan, Dec, Nov, Oct, Sep, Aug`

Comment: What is the data type of the column which stores months information which you need to sort..also which DBMS you are using?

Comment: Hi, month can be int such as Jan = 1, Feb = 2, or it can be a 3-letter string. Updated my tags, thanks!

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your select query, so that it will be easier to help you regarding order by.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `custom sort`

```
SELECT Datename(month, Cast(mon + '1900' AS DATE)) AS [Month]
FROM   (VALUES ('Jul'),('Jun'),('May'),('Apr'),
               ('Mar'),('Feb'),('Jan'),('Dec'),
               ('Nov'),('Oct'),('Sep'),('Aug')) tc (mon)
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN Month(Cast(mon + '1900' AS DATE)) - Month(Getdate()) = 0 THEN -2
            ELSE Sign(Month(Cast(mon + '1900' AS DATE)) - Month(Getdate()))
          END,
          Month(Cast(mon + '1900' AS DATE)) - Month(Getdate()) DESC
```

If you just want the first three letters of the `month` in result then use

`Select LEFT(Datename(month, Cast(mon + '1900' AS DATE)),3) as [Month]`

- [**Sqlfiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ffa43/9)

Answer (score 0):

The following is another way. It is based on using SYSOBJECTS as a convenient numbers table and uses today's date (i.e. GETDATE()) to derive the current date.

```
SELECT TOP 12
  SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(Month,  -ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) + 1, GETDATE())), 1, 3) AS MonthStr,
  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(Month,  -ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) + 1, GETDATE())), 0) AS FirstDayOfMonth
FROM
  sysobjects
```

It gives you a result set like:

```
MonthStr    FirstDayOfMonth
--------    ---------------
Jul         2015-07-01 00:00:00.000
Jun         2015-06-01 00:00:00.000
May         2015-05-01 00:00:00.000
Apr         2015-04-01 00:00:00.000
Mar         2015-03-01 00:00:00.000
Feb         2015-02-01 00:00:00.000
Jan         2015-01-01 00:00:00.000
Dec         2014-12-01 00:00:00.000
Nov         2014-11-01 00:00:00.000
Oct         2014-10-01 00:00:00.000
Sep         2014-09-01 00:00:00.000
Aug         2014-08-01 00:00:00.000
```

Change the `TOP 12` to any other value to expand or reduce the dates emitted. You can JOIN to this table in your SP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,ISNULL(NULLIF((MONTH(GETDATE()) + MONTHNUM)%12,0),12) -1,0)),3)
FROM (VALUES(12),(11),(10),(9),(8),(7),(6),(5),(4),(3),(2),(1)) A (MONTHNUM)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
SELECT MonthNumber
      ,LEFT(DATENAME(Month,DATEADD( MONTH , MonthNumber , 0 )-1),3) MonthName
FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),
            (7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) mn(MonthNumber)
ORDER BY CASE WHEN MonthNumber > DATEPART(m,GETDATE())
        THEN MonthNumber - 12
        ELSE
        MonthNumber
        END DESC
```